# Can a block set on a inclined plane fall vertically downwards?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

At the top of a wedge of inclination $\theta$, a block is kept. There are no external forces acting on this block in horizontal direction.

Is is possible for this block to fall vertically downwards?

(Image below for illustration/clarity ONLY regarding my question)

[image]

I have tried to evaluate the answer using FBDs and no matter how I attempt it, my final answer comes out to be either $\sin\theta = 0$ or $cos\theta = 0$ but for either of those conditions, it wouldn't be an inclined plane.

I have also referred to the following questions asked on this site but I haven't got the answer to my question:

[Free body diagram of block on accelerating wedge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277412)

[A block on inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/419412)

[block slides on smooth triangular wedge kept on smooth floor.Find velocity of wedge when block reaches bottom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51551)

Please notify me in the comments if more clarity is needed anywhere.

Comment: "There is no external force in this system except for the gravitational forces", there is also an external force from the table, no?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes there is. What I meant was there's no external force in the horizontal direction. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a block set on a inclined plane fall vertically downwards

Only if the mass of the incline, $M$, were zero.

Since the only external forces acting on the combination of the two blocks are vertical (gravity and the normal reaction force of the supporting surface on $M$), the center of mass  (COM) of the two block system can only undergo vertical downward motion.

Since block $M$ can only move horizontally to the left in the reference frame of the floor, block $m$ must move downward and to the right in the reference frame of the floor, in such a manner that the horizontal components of the two motions cancel so that the  COM moves downward. The greater the mass of $m$ is compared to that of $M$ the smaller the component of the motion of $m$ to the right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a really nice explanation that has cleared my query :D

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: There's another weird edge case where the block can fall straight down:  $\theta = 90°$.  That's about as realistic as assuming that $M = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert agree. Of course then you can no longer call it an incline as well as no longer call it a wedge